# Ruby on Rails and geochart SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement [geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) on a users's model but i am having problems with my sql query on my helper method. The user model has country as one of the fields.

My problem is grouping and passing the data to a js

**users.js**

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
//    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
//        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
//        ['Germany', 200],
//        ['United States', 300],
//        ['Brazil', 400],
//        ['Canada', 500],
//        ['France', 600],
//        ['RU', 700]
//    ]);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(['users_country_data']);

    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

**index.html.rb**

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "chart_div", style: "width: 400px; height:200px;",  data: {users: users_country_data} %>
```

**users.helpers.rb**

```
  def users_country_data
      {
         Country: @users.group("country"),
         Popularity:  @users.count(:group => "country")
      }

  end
```

Edit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry you spent a complete day on this, rails and ruby should be more easier than that.

```
def users_country_data
  countries = @users.select('distinct country').map(&:country)
  countries.collect { |country| [country, @users.where(country: country).count] }.to_s
end
```

that will give you the array for js, like:

```
[["Argentina", 100], ["USA", 200]]
```

If you want to add the headers as well:

```
def users_country_data
  countries = @users.select('distinct country').map(&:country)
  countries.collect { |country| [country, @users.where(country: country).count] }.unshift(['Country', 'Popularity']).to_s
end
```

---

You are getting **wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)** because @users is an array of users, any reason for which @users is an array of users and not a ActiveRecord relationship?

EDIT: I used = instead of == for comparison

```
def users_country_data
  countries = @users.map(&:country).uniq
  countries.collect { |country| [country, @users.collect {|u| u.country == country}.count] }.to_s
end
```

---

After the chat, and having in mind you want the graph for all the users:

```
def users_country_data
  countries = User.select('distinct country').map(&:country)
  countries.collect { |country| [country, User.where(country: country).count] }.unshift(['Country', 'Popularity']).to_s
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I truly appreciate. However "I get wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" and it's pointing to countries = @users.select('distinct country').map(&:country)

Comment: \@users should be an ActiveRecord relationship, not sure why you get an Array of users in \@users and why you are doing math on it, its very ineffective, I added the code to make it work with an array of users, but you should update the code so \@users in an activerecord relationship, you should earn a lot of speed by letting the database engine to do the grouping and the count. (if \@users is an array of Users, it will be ruby doing the grouping and it will be slower)

Comment: Thank you, i will accept your answer, there are no errors but the graph isn't showing yet. But i think you have got me far. I will try and figure out why it's not showing the map. When i look at the HTML i get div data-users="[[&quot;France&quot;, 4], [&quot;Canada&quot;, 4], [&quot;South Africa&quot;, 4]]" id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height:500px;"></div>

Comment: Actually, it's showing the total number of users on the system (4) for all countries.

Comment: That's because its escaping the html. Try with:
<%= raw(users_country_data) %>

Comment: Can you do a: <%= @users.inspect %> and update your question with that information? I'm telling you, \@users should not be an array of users, it should be an ActiveRecord relationship. But even if an array of users, we can fix it.

Comment: Updated question. I have users from different countries.

Comment: So the dump shows that you only have 4 users, that @users is an array of Users, and that the country for all those 4 users is **South Africa**, I'm not sure what you want to archive, but I'll need more information in order to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27267/discussion-between-vezu-and-rorra)

Comment: This is how my html looks like <div data-users="[["France", 4], ["Canada", 4], ["South Africa", 4], ["Jamaica", 4]]" id="users_div" style="width: 400px; height:500px;"></div>